# Python3 + Google App Engine + MySQL

Tags: python, sql, django, google-app-engine, pip

I have been struggling with this for quite awhile now and I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere...

I am using this tutorial to set up a django app using Google app engine:
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

I am now on the step "Run the app from your local computer"

I am recieving the following error when I try and run the django mirgate commands:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")
```

Any idea where how I can fix this?

I tried to install mysqlclient using pip however i got the following error also:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yt/ykmtcb9j4tzfxh3rmzfmzxkh0000gp/T/pip-build-xzqmic32/mysqlclient/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The guide you referenced is for the GAE standard environment, which requires python 2.7, it doesn't support pyton 3. The migration scripts are typically standalone python scripts, you need to either setup the proper GAE development server environment for them or execute them from inside your GAE app code (say by hooking them up to a handler).

Comment: Looking to setup a proper GAE development server. How would I go about doing this? Are there any references you can point me to?

Comment: Or really any better/updated tutorials to getting a Python Django app up and running on GAE?

Comment: I'm not a django user, so I can't really tell. But I know that there is no such thing as a single/standard django setup, which is why I think you're not gonna find a single good-for-all guide. Especially on GAE - django wasn't designed for it. To complicate matters further there isn't a single/standard GAE setup/context - there are many possible combinations of smaller things.  You'll have to pick  your solution, break it down into smaller items and deal with one obstacle at a time. My earlier comment listed just a few obvious items to consider, there are likely many others.

Comment: You should have maybe started here: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/